# Where does wordpress store the FTP credentials?

Tags: uploads, ftp

When wordpress asks for FTP information to upgrade, you type it in and then it seems to store it for future use (for future upgrades, and maybe also for media uploads?)

Where does it store these details? Is it in a file? In the database?

I'm trying to figure out what information is being used to access the server.

Tried grep-ing for `ftp` in the php files and didnt see anything. This also doesn't seem to be a setting that is exposed in the admin interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your browser (Chrome?) saved your input.  NOTE: WordPress allows you to save FTP credentials in the wp-config.php file, but if you grep-ed and you didn't see any definitions for FTP in there, it may just be that your browser saved your input.

Comment: Not saved in the browser. This is for a site that I probably entered the config info in a few years ago.

Comment: My Chrome auto-fill has text field inputs from a few years ago because I login to sync browser settings. But, I hear ya.

Comment: Hm, yeah I think there are two different situations here. One is where it actually prompts for FTP information (in this case it could be saved or not) and the other where it doesnt even prompt it. Maybe it is the permissions issue as suggested below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't. WP Filesystem API will ask for FTP credentials, but it will do so for each operation. They aren't stored persistently.

They *can* be stored persistently by hardcoding into `wp-config.php`, but WP won't do that itself, it's a user action.

Note that WP only asks for FTP credentials *if* it cannot modify files without them. If specific setup used to ask for them and stopped then likely the server configuration or file permissions had changed and now allow WP to manipulate files without going through FTP.

Comment: That is probably the difference -- one sites I was working with probably had some ability to modify the files without FTP, and the other probably didn't have the right permissions so prompted for FTP settings.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something just now that might be an answer. Rarst says WP doesn't store FTP credentials in the DB but I just discovered in a MySQL dump file I was working on, that in the `wp_options` table, there is the following:

```
15122,'ftp_credentials','a:3:{s:8:\"hostname\";s:27:\"mysiteurl\";s:8:\"username\";s:7:\"myusernmae\";s:15:\"connection_type\";s:4:\"ftps\";}','yes'
```

As a value to be entered. I think that when permissions are messed up, and it asks for your credentials, those values might actually be stored in wp_options. This was in an old version of WP, 4.4.2, I think, but it was indeed in the database.

Comment: how to find that row? I don't see anyting similar in my wp_options. Does it mean that FTP access is disabled?